Full relaxation of 2D slab model
I am trying to relax (lattice parameters and atomic positions) the crystal structure of 2D system (slab model). I am able to get forces reduced with tags like cell_dofree= '2Dxy' or 'c', however pressure is too significant to accept. I am looking for suggestions on fully relaxing the 2D slab systems using quantum ESPRESSO. My vc-relax input file typically looks like :
calculation = 'vc-relax'
  etot_conv_thr =   4.0000000000d-05
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'NiTe'
  pseudo_dir = '../nc-sr-04_pbe_stringent'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'low'
  nstep = 500
/
&SYSTEM
  degauss =   2.0000000000d-02
  ecutrho =   2.0000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   5.0000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 4
  nosym = .true.
  ntyp = 2
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'cold'
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   8.0000000000d-7
  electron_maxstep = 80
  mixing_beta =   4.0000000000d-01
/
&IONS
/
&CELL
cell_dofree = '2Dxy'
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ni     58.6934  Ni.upf
Te     127.6    Te.upf
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Ni               0.6666666291        0.3333333415        0.4687894791
Te               0.6666667182        0.3333333228        0.5706946359
Ni               0.3333333703        0.6666666584        0.5312101766
Te               0.3333332823        0.6666666773        0.4293057084
K_POINTS automatic
20 20 1 0 0 0
CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom
      3.8828468972       0.0000000000       0.0000000000
     -1.9414234487       3.3626440520       0.0000000000
      0.0000000000       0.0000000000      23.7475238445


Why are you forcing the lattice parameters relaxation?

My aim is to construct Wannier functions from Bloch states. I am not sure whether I should do full relaxation or not. Kindly explain.

@Camps I am using CIF structure from MC2D database. Is it sufficient to relax atomic positions (i.e. minimise forces) only for 2D slab models? In other words, can we ignore residual non-negligible stress/pressure along all directions?

Sometimes low ecut gives high pressure. Because of low quality. Did you do converge test?

I am using norm-conserving pseudopotential for which ecutrho is recommeded to be 4 times ecutwfc. Should I increase?

In the case of norm-conserving pseudopotential, you just use default value(ecutrho = ecutwfc*4). I think you have to convergence test first. and take proper ecutwfc value.
